# how to change the color of the arrow of guide navigation not the current position arrow?

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to change the white color of the guiding arrow not the 
 current green arrow, could any one help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not provided in the SDK so, you cannot change the color of the guidance arrow.